# I can't get out of grub rescue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I had Linux dual-booted on my Windows 10 laptop and I tried to remove Linux, so I could start fresh, by deleting the Linux partitions and merging them with my Windows one.

I now can't get out of Grub Rescue mode and I have tried everything that has been posted on here.

Comment: How do you merge a partition for two OS?

Comment: I did it by deleting everything off the Linux one and then merging it with the Windows one

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by booting on your widows media and use and run bootrec. This will remove the part of grub that still lives on your MBR.